# Oracle encoding problems

Tags: oracle, encoding

There is aan Oracle database with regional encoding for Kazakh language. There is also a client, but it uses UTF encoding.
When i update db field in Kazakh through pl/sql developer or call update proc in web application, these special characters becomes '?'.
But if i locate ora18n java file in oracle sql developer folder and update field in Kazakh, everithing works well.
How can solve my problem? If you need any db or clinet conf, u are welcome!

Comment: What I suggest is that you use SUBSTr and ASCII to inspect that actual character code of the data in the database to verify whether the data is actually the correct character, and is just being displayed incorrectly in various clients.

Comment: Please state the NLS_LANG setting for the database server machine and also in the client machine which use to connect to the database (user the regedit command to see this). Moreover post the results of the following query SELECT * FROM NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS.